# Select all text in a UITextField using Swift

Tags: swift, uitextfield

How do you programatically select all the text in a Swift text field?

```
var textField:UITextField = UITextField()
textField.frame = CGRectMake(2, 25, 200, 20)
textField.text = "hello"
textField.font = UIFont(name: "Verdana", size: 12)
textField.textColor = UIColor.blackColor()
textField.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
```

Or at least make the text immediately editable?

Thanks

Andrew

Answer (score 29, accepted):

```
textField.becomeFirstResponder()
textField.selectAll(nil)
```

Answer (score 34):

It works in the same way like in Objective-C:

```
textField.becomeFirstResponder()

textField.selectedTextRange = textField.textRange(from: textField.beginningOfDocument, to: textField.endOfDocument)
```

Answer (score 6):

In case you need this to work with a SwiftUI TextField, you can use [Introspect](https://github.com/siteline/SwiftUI-Introspect):

```
import Introspect

private class TextFieldObserver: NSObject {
    @objc
    func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
        textField.selectAll(nil)
    }
}

struct ContentView {
    private let textFieldObserver = TextFieldObserver()
    var body: some View {
        TextField(...)
            .introspectTextField { textField in
                textField.addTarget(
                    self.textFieldObserver,
                    action: #selector(TextFieldObserver.textFieldDidBeginEditing),
                    for: .editingDidBegin
                )
            }
    }
}
```

Note that you shouldn't override `textField.delegate` as SwiftUI sets up its own delegate that is supposed to be hidden from you.

Comment: Great looking library, but I wish it exposed selection events for UITextField

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

Make sure you conform to the `UITextFieldDelegate` and implement:

```
func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
        //highlights all text
        textField.selectedTextRange = textField.textRange(from: textField.beginningOfDocument, to: textField.endOfDocument)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If the previously solutions doesn't help

```
    func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            textField.selectedTextRange = textField.textRange(from: textField.beginningOfDocument, to: textField.endOfDocument)
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I make with this

```swift
override func selectAll(_ sender: Any?) {
  textView.selectAll(sender)
}
```